# Creating an array of a specified length

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I have a minimum value for an array,

```
 min = 50
```

and a max value:

```
  max = 60
```

How do I create an array that starts at 50, ends at 60, and has a total of 6 values in the list? Something like the following, that could also handle creating decimal values instead of integers.

```
array = [50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60]
```

Comment: Look for numpy linspace and numpy arange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
np.linspace(50, 60, num=6, endpoint=True, dtype=int)
array([50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60])
```